# Mongoose: How to find() based on nested object value

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a schema desing like this:

```js
const UserDataFrameWork = new mongoose.Schema({
HighScores: {
        Dodge: {
            TenCent: {type:Number, default: 0},
            FiftyCent: {type:Number, default: 0},
            Dolsu: {type:Number, default: 0},
            FiveDolsu: {type:Number, default: 0},
            TenDolsu: {type:Number, default: 0},
            FiftyDolsu: {type:Number, default: 0},
        },
        example: { 
            test: {type:Number, default: 0}
          }
       }
}

const User = mongoose.model('User', UserDataFrameWork)

module.exports = User
```

I am trying to find the users that have highscore of 0 in Dodge.TenCent like this:

```js
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router();
const DB = require('../models/User')

router.get('/', async (req,res) =>{

const Tgames = await DB.find({"HighScores.Dodge.TenCent": 0})

console.log(Tgames)
res.render('testejs.ejs')

})

module.exports = router;
```

This doesn't work, I can't figure out how to find based on the value of nested object.
Is it even possible to have object inside of object in mongoose schema? I am pretty new to mongoose so sorry if I'm doing something wrong? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: In what way is this not working?  What output or error are you getting?

Comment: It returns a empty array, I know for a fact there are documents where the Dodge tencent highscore is equal to zero. @user20042973

Answer (score 0):

One of my nested queries looks like this:

```
let ppdata = await Pallet.find({sscc: {$in: ssccArray}, 'po.edi_file_name': /PO/i }, ' sscc po.season po.edi_file_name').slice('po', -1).lean().exec();
```

Have you tested:

```
const Tgames = await DB.find({"HighScores.Dodge.TenCent": 0}).exec()
```

Comment: I tried it, unfortunately didn't work. @zs1rcm

Answer (score 0):

I kind of found the answer! Not to my question but, I'm not stuck with this anymore. So when I tried to find() something with the value of 0 it was not returning anything, but when I tried finding something with value two it returned. It is not a problem if I can't find anything with the value 0 because I believe it is the same as undefined, because I have set the default to 0.